# How does a colored glass work?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, vision

If I look through a colored glass, I see all the objects colored as the glass.

***Why?***

***How does the color of the glass transfer to the image?***

Answer (score 1):

A colored glass spears to have a specific color because it only lets parts of the white sun light pass through it. So when you look at a glass and looks red for your, this is because the direct or indirect light from your source is passing through your glass and only the red parts are coming out of it.
You can rather think of it that every object/image you look at is already a mixture of monochromatic images and with using a color filter you are looking only at a mixed subset of these images.

Printers typically use cyan, magenta, yellow and black as their monochromatic color basis. The individual monochromatic images are shown for the example image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is [color perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision), and [color by frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum) . The answer by user_na is about the perception of color, which is a biological build up in the cones of the retina.

A glass can absorb all frequencies other than the frequency of the color red , 400–484 THz in frequency. But red can also be perceived by a [combination of frequencies,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html) , if only this combination of frequencies passes the glass and all the rest are absorbed, again the glass will look red.

Absorption means that the atoms, molecules and mainly the lattice interact with the photons of that energy/frequencies ( E=h*nu) and is opaque to them.